# Calling out onclick button on style

Tags: html

I'm curious if it's possible to call out my onclick function on style.

For example:

```
<a style="margin-right: 10px; onclick=\"return confirm("Confirm?") href=""  title="Confirm" ><img src="Confirm.png" alt="Confirm" /></a>
```

I would want to call out my onclick event over here, is it possible ? It can reference to next page but not onclick function. Kindly advise

Comment: No it isn't. Can you explain what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Want to give a confirmation popup from there?

Comment: Well, I would do `<input type="image" src="confirm.png" alt="confirm" width="xx" height="xx" onClick="return confirm("Confirm?");" />`

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you were to assign that style to a class, you could call it on class.

Comment: got other ways ? Like href from the page and return a confirm ?